# Regex few conditions at once occurence

Tags: regex

I am wondering what should I change to make this scope run well.

What I need to find is all the occurences of the code with following structure:

```
new MyObject(parameters)
{somethingHere}
```

There may be anything for MyObject, parameters and something here. Moreover between (...) and {...} may be new line or just spaces.

What I have tried to do is:

```
new [^(]*([^)]*)){[^}]*}
```

However this doesn't work well. I have tried then to find something on http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html and the following section was very promising, but failed: http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html .

May anyone give me a hint what should I change in my expression ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will `new\s+\w+\(.*\)[\s\S][^}]+}` do the job ?

Test [here](http://regexr.com/3cg4i).

[image]

Comment: thank you for advise, tomorrow I am going to check it on the whole code, however looking like perfect, greatings for you !

Answer (score 1):

With below changes in your expression it might work

```
new \w+\(.*\)\s{[\s\S]+?}
```

However, it has limitation to match if any of the subroutine has inner blocks. For example, this one perfectly matches

```
new MyObject(parameters)
{
   int a;
   somethingHere 
}
```

But it will match only partially for this code

```
new MyObject(parameters)
{
   int a;
   somethingHere

   if (a == x)
   {
     someotherthinghere
   }
}
```